# Variable scope in C# outside try block

Tags: c#, scope

I am very new to C#, and confused about variable scope. This is the block of code, I have written, but when I am trying to access the value of a and b outside try block, it gives me compile time error

```
class TestConditionalStatements
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a, b;
        try
        {
            a = 10;
            b = 20;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
        }
        //This line gives compile time error
        ConditionalStatements c = new ConditionalStatements(a, b);
        string result;
        c.checkValidity(c, out result);
        Console.WriteLine(result);


    }
}
```

Comment: or more likely the ConditionalStatements constructor doesn't take integers as arguments

Comment: Hi, please, always post the error as well.

Comment: Hi, please, always try to ask an actual question, it helps other to address your issue more directly.

Answer (score 5):

Variable a and b might not be initialized at that line.
Lets say that an exception is thrown on the line:

```
a = 10;
```

Then what is the value of b?
You need to either initialize a and b with a value before the try catch:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
try
{
    a = 10;
    b = 20;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Write(e.Message);
}
```

or give them a value in the catch clause:

```
int a , b ;
try
{
    a = 10;
    b = 20;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    Console.Write(e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`a` and `b` are not yet initialized.  The code path exists where an exception might occur before they are assigned in your `try` block and the compiler recognizes that.  Either set `a` and `b` to something before the `try` block e.g. `int a = 0, b = 0;`, or re-think your logic.